# Scraping with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to dig a little deeper with scrapy, but can only get the title of what i am scrapying and not any of the details.  Here is the code that I have so far:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from tcgplayer1.items import Tcgplayer1Item

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "tcg"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.tcgplayer.com/"]
    start_urls = ["http://store.tcgplayer.com/magic/journey-into-nyx?PageNumber=1"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//div[@class='magicCard']")
        vendor = hxs.select("//tr[@class='vendor']")
        items = []

        for titles in titles:
            item = Tcgplayer1Item()
            item ["cardname"] = titles.select("//li[@class='cardName']/a/text()").extract()
            item ["price"] = vendor.select("//td[@class='price']/br/text()").extract()
            item ["quantity"] = vendor.select("//td[@class='quantity']/td/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

I cannot get the price and quantity to show any results.  Each card has several vendors each with their own prices and quantities.  I think that is where i am having problems.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, here's the fixed version of the code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from tcgplayer1.items import Tcgplayer1Item


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "tcg"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.tcgplayer.com/"]
    start_urls = ["http://store.tcgplayer.com/magic/journey-into-nyx?PageNumber=1"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath("//div[@class='magicCard']")
        for title in titles:
            item = Tcgplayer1Item()
            item["cardname"] = title.xpath(".//li[@class='cardName']/a/text()").extract()[0]

            vendor = title.xpath(".//tr[@class='vendor ']")
            item["price"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//td[@class='price']/text())").extract()
            item["quantity"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//td[@class='quantity']/text())").extract()
            yield item
```

There were multiple issues with the code:

- the `vendor` class name needs to contain a trailing space: "vendor " - it was tricky to find
- there are multiple vendors per-item - you need to define `vendor` inside the loop
- you are redefining `titles` variable in the loop
- xpath expressions in the loop should be relative `.//`
- use `Selector` instead of deprecated `HtmlXPathSelector`
- use `xpath()` instead of deprecated `select()`
- use `normalize-space()` to eliminate new-lines and extra spaces in `price` and `quantity` xpaths

Comment: this is really close ... the one issue is that the prices and quantities don't match the cards.  It shows the same list of prices for each card ... as well as quantity.  This was much closer though.

Comment: @user3680812 there was a slight problem, I've updated the code, recheck it please.

Comment: The ".//tr" did it ... ty so much.

Comment: @user3680812 glad it helped. It was an interesting problem. Consider accepting the answer if you think it deserves. Thanks.

Comment: how hard is it too make this code run through page1 to however many pages are there?

Comment: @user3680812 well, it is a good candidate for a separate SO question. But, the idea is basically get the last page number from pagination part of a page and dynamically define your `start_urls` by overriding [`start_requests()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) method of your spider.

Answer (score 1):

First, you could change

```
item ["price"] = vendor.select("//td[@class='price']/br/text()").extract()
item ["quantity"] = vendor.select("//td[@class='quantity']/td/text()").extract()
```

To:

```
item ["price"] = titles.select("//td[@class='price']/br/text()").extract()
item ["quantity"] = titles.select("//td[@class='quantity']/td/text()").extract()
```

This will ensure you are only getting price and quantity rows for the card you want.

You may also have to remove the /br and /td from the selectors, so your code would look like this:

```
item ["price"] = titles.select("//td[@class='price']/text()").extract()
item ["quantity"] = titles.select("//td[@class='quantity']/text()").extract()
```